# How to access properties from the prototype chain that are shadowed by own properties?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Let's create an object which inherits from another anonymous object:

```
var obj = Object.create({
    func: function () { alert('Inherited method'); }
});
```

Now `obj` inherits the `func` method from that anonymous object (`obj`'s prototype link points to that anonymous object).

```
obj.func(); // alerts 'Inherited method'
```

But if we assign a `func` property on `obj` itself, the inherited `func` property will be **shadowed**:

```
obj.func = function () { alert('Own method'); };

obj.func(); // alerts 'Own method'
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PLxHB/

Now, if we wanted to invoke that shadowed `func` method (the one that alerts `'Inherited method'`), what would be a good way to do that?

I've already come up one solution - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/PLxHB/1/) - but it's kind-of a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).func();
```

will make sure the inherited function gets executed.

In older browsers (the above is ES5), you can use

```
obj.__proto__.func();
```

but this is deprecated.

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/PLxHB/5/

Comment: Ah yes... ES5 comes to save the day `:)`

Comment: It's a pity that they didn't go with a method instead - like `obj.proto().func()`. That would have been more convenient...